# ggsurvplot: correct plotting of two time points for prognosing future

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to prognose resource of a profession in a country assuming that they work from graduation age until retirement age.

The problem is that with the prognosis "8 or 16 added per year" we should have resource increase, not decrease. **What am I doing wrong?**

**Data**

*time1 - from what year specialist is available as a resource (0 is 2022)

time2 - from what year specialist will retire

status1 - always "1" as all of them will retire

time1 = 5 and time2 = 10 means that this hypothetical specialist is available from year 5 (2027) up to year 10 (2032)*

```
library(tidyverse)

data = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2s628a9sn84lm1/data.csv?dl=1")
data
```

[image]

**Survfit object**

This seems to work: the number of available specialists increases with "16 added per year"

```
library(survival)
fit = survfit(Surv(time1, time2, status) ~ group, data = data)
fit
```

[image]

**Kaplan-Meier curves**

This seems to be erroneous as all lines show decrease of the resource; however, risk table shows that the total number of these persons increase.

```
library(survminer)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = data,
           xlab = "Years from today",
           ylab = "Proportion",
           risk.table = T,
           break.x.by = 5,
           legend = "right",
           xlim = c(0, 29),
           legend.title = "Prognosis",
           surv.scale = "percent",
           tables.height = 0.40)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are hoping to do, but does changing the ggsurvplot to represent cumulative events with the argument `fun = event` help at all / get you closer to what you want? If I'm understanding correctly it would better illustrate time to outcome i.e. retirement?

Comment: Tried, "fun = "event"" does not do the trick. My point is that the first two rows in risk table actually show increasing numbers, meaning that these prognoses show increasing number of specialists in the future. However, when checking the curves, all of them show that proportion of these specialists resource is in decline, decreasing. Why's that?

Comment: You've misunderstood the purpose of `survfit` and kaplan-meier. The fact that survfit gives you a reasonable looking table is just a random coincidence, it isn't actually an appropriate method for this type of analysis. Both methods assume that all participants are "alive" at time 0, but that we are only observing whether they die/fail during certain periods (time1 to time2). In your case the number of participants is actually growing over time and you're interested in the number alive, not the proportion alive. So you'll have to either find a different method or code the analysis yourself.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me which close-vote reason fit this best. The questioner has completely missed the point of survival analysis. He clearly wants something else, perhaps a simulation. So I edited the tags but think it is too unclear to really be answered unless it gets editted.